# How to treat 'activity' panel with no activity

Tags: gui-design, layout, progress

I have a Web based UI, and it has a one line panel in which a summary of ongoing background activity is shown. When background activity is occurring, a spinner shows in the panel with a summary of the activity, e.g. "Scanned 10 of 20 folders". When activity completes, the text disappears. To the right of the panel is a button to invoke fresh "scans".

[image: Ongoing scan]

The activity is long running, and is not always changed as a result of user action - it could be *another* user's action, something on a schedule, or something invoked automatically as the result of some event.

When there's no text there, it just looks like an empty space with the button floating off to the right. I wonder if some sort of placeholder should appear instead so the user knows that activity may appear there.

[image]

Am I the only one to think it looks like a waste of space?

I don't want to make the panel appear and disappear because I personally dislike Web pages that move contents up and down a page. Always seems to occur just when I'm about to click a link...

Are there any broad guidelines as to what to do about these content areas?

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree the content should not shift.

I would put a message showing the "staleness" of the data, e.g.

```
"Last scanned 10 minutes ago"
```

or

```
"Last scanned on 6/27 at 9:30"
```

This gives the user the context they need to decide whether or not they want to trigger a manual re-scan (or helps explain why something they are looking for isn't shown- it is too new).

Comment: That's a good idea, and better than a dumb "Activity will appear here". Would you advise different styling, e.g. greyed out text, italics?

Comment: How about a (green/gray) checkmark to indicate that the last scan was successful? If something fails, do you have means to notify the user? You might add a red text to indicate that the last scan failed.

Comment: I agree with Leon and yes- making it visually less prominent is a good idea since it's not something the user *has* to read or make a decision on, since it's just contextual information.